# What is the best approach of clustering if you know number of elements in each cluster?

Tags: clustering, python, unsupervised-learning

I want to predict sporting event with knockout system tournament. Data have some features attached to each athlete. I know that there are determined number of results such as:

`W(winner) = 1
F = 1
SF = 2
QF = 4
and so on`

And I want to predict result for every athlete. I think that clustering is the right way to solve such problem.

Which is the best way of such clustering in Python libraries? I know that some cluster estimators in scikit-learn have argument n_clusters (amount of clusters), but I didn't find any argument that determines number of elements in every cluster.

Edit: add dataframe example structure (including predicted results in column 'y_example'):

```
    pl  f1  f2      f3      f4  f5  f6  f7  f8         y_example
    0   27  587927  0.498   44  11  0   1   4727329    QF
    1   25  742400  0.588   52  30  9   17  1972378    SF
    2   30  707331  0.44    26  5   2   2   -28808492  F
    3   25  636268  0.434   9   0   0   0   -12889458  QF
    4   28  890370  0.522   34  9   6   6   -18179225  QF
    5   24  710522  0.459   19  4   1   0   -18973768  W
    6   30  817982  0.51    20  3   2   1   -20905065  SF
    7   26  692898  0.499   33  10  0   0   6786944    QF
```

Comment: can you post an example dataset and explain the structure? The question is not quite clear

Comment: Edited question

Comment: Im not sure if clustering is the way to go here? For doing so you would have to assume, that whith each step in the tourney there is a jump in distance - the distance within one tourney-step must be smaller then between tourney-steps to get this going. But - worst case - in a tourney player A and B could be true gods and C to Z are not skilled at all. So A and B are very similar but chances, that they wont face each other before great final are just 50%.

Comment: You seem to want to predict classes, and not use clustering at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think we would need more information than what you have provided. Selecting a clustering method depends on many factors:

- Size of the data (Unfortunately very large data is difficult to cluster)
- Types of variables (continuous? categorical?)
- Expected distribution of the clusters

For example:

- Hierarchical clustering is very complex for big volumes of data
- K-means works good with big volumes of data but the euclidean distance is meaningless for clustering in some cases and it doesn't scale for massive volumes of data
- The BF-R algorithm can work well on massive data sets, but it makes works only under the assumption that the clusters are normally distributed across the centroid and the mean and standard deviation for a cluster may differ for different dimensions, but the dimensions must be independent

You can [review this presentation](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mining/2009/clustering.pdf) to get a basic idea about clustering.
And also check this video for the [BF-R algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NP1Zk8MY08k) for clustering massive data sets.

Comment: size of data is small - 32 rows, types of variables are all continuous and expected distribution of the clusters actually provided in question: W - 1, F - 1, SF - 2, QF - 4, R16 - 8, R32 - 16.